# Find the path of an JSON element with dynamic key with Play JSON

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I am using Play Framework with Scala. I have the following JSON structure:

```
{
    "a": 1540554574847,
    "b": 2,
    "c": {
    "pep3lpnp1n1ugmex5uevekg5k20wkfq3": {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 1,
    "c": 1,
    "d": 1
    },
    "p3zgudnf7tzqvt50g7lpr2ryno7yugmy": {
    "b": [
    "d10e5600d11e5517"
    ],
    "c": 1,
    "d": 1,
    "e": 1,
    "g": 1,
    "h": [
    "d10e5600d11e5517",
    "d10e5615d11e5527",
    "d10e5605d11e5520",
    "d10e5610d11e5523",
    "d10e5620d11e5530"
    ],
    "q": "a_z6smu56gstysjpqbzp21ruxii6g2ph00"
    },
    "33qfthhugr36f5ts4251glpqx0o373pe": {
    "b": [
    "d10e5633d11e5536"
    ],
    "c": 1,
    "d": 1,
    "e": 1,
    "g": 1,
    "h": [
    "d10e5638d11e5539",
    "d10e5633d11e5536",
    "d10e5643d11e5542",
    "d10e5653d11e5549",
    "d10e5648d11e5546"
    ],
    "q": "a_cydo6wu1ds340j3q6qxeig97thocttsp"
    }
    }
    }
```

I need to fetch values from paths
`"c" -> "pep3lpnp1n1ugmex5uevekg5k20wkfq3" -> "b"`,
`"c" -> "p3zgudnf7tzqvt50g7lpr2ryno7yugmy" -> "b"`,
`"c" -> "33qfthhugr36f5ts4251glpqx0o373pe" -> "b"`, and so on, where `"pep3lpnp1n1ugmex5uevekg5k20wkfq3"` is dynamic and changes for every JSON input.

Output should be like Seq(object(q,b,c)).

Comment: What would be the output of the following input in your case ?

Comment: Output should be like Seq(object(q,b,c)).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to know which generated key belongs to which value you can use [recursive path](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJson#Recursive-path-%5C%5C) `\\` operator:

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json
import play.api.libs.json._

val jsonText = """{
   "a":1540554574847,
   "b":2,
   "c":{
      "onegeneratedkey":{
         "a":1,
         "b":1,
         "c":1,
         "d":1
      },
      "secondsonegeneratedkey":{
         "a":1,
         "b": [1, 2, 3],
         "c":1,
         "d":1
      }
   }
}"""

val result: Seq[JsValue] = Json.parse(jsonText) \ "c" \\ "b"
// res: List(1, [1,2,3])
```

UPD.

To get all values stored inside object with generated-keys, one can use `JsObject#values`:

```
val valuesSeq: Seq[JsValue] = (Json.parse(jsonText) \ "c").toOption // get 'c' field
  .collect {case o: JsObject => o.values.toSeq} // get all object that corresponds to generated keys
  .getOrElse(Seq.empty)
// res: Seq({"a":1,"b":1,"c":1,"d":1}, {"a":1,"b":[1,2,3],"c":1,"d":1})

val valuesABC = valuesSeq.map(it => (it \ "a", it \ "b", it \ "c"))
// res: Seq((JsDefined(1),JsDefined(1),JsDefined(1)), (JsDefined(1),JsDefined([1,2,3]),JsDefined(1)))
```

Comment: Is there any way to get a,b,c parameters using this way as it is returning seq("b")? I need the value mapping as well.(a,b,c)(a,b,c).....

Answer (score 0):

I misread the question, and this is the modified version.

Here I used json.pick to read JsObject and iterate the keys from there.

Ps: You don't have to create Reads or the case classes, but it should made the caller program more readable.

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json
import play.api.libs.json._

val jsonText =
  """{
    "top": {
      "level2a": {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 1,
        "c": 1,
        "d": 1
      },
      "level2b": {
        "a": 2,
        "b": 2,
        "nested": {
          "b": "not interested"
        }
      }
    }
  }"""

case class Data(k: String, v: Int)
case class Datas(list: Seq[Data])

object Datas {
  implicit val reads: Reads[Datas] = (__ \ "top").json.pick.map {
    case obj: JsObject =>
      new Datas(obj.keys.flatMap(k => (obj \ k \ "b").validate[Int] match {
        case JsSuccess(v, _) => Some(Data(k, v))
        case _ => None
      }).toSeq)
  }
}

Json.parse(jsonText).validate[Datas].asOpt match {
  case Some(d) => println(s"found: $d")
  case _ => println("not found")
}
```

---

To deserialize the internal structure within level2, you may choose to create the internal structure and use Json.reads to create the default reads. So long as the data structure is known and predictable.

For example

```
case class Internal(a: Int, b: Int, c: Option[Int], d: Option[Int])
object Internal {
  implicit val reads = Json.reads[Internal]
}
case class Data(k: String, v: Internal)
case class Datas(list: Seq[Data])
object Datas {
  implicit val reads: Reads[Datas] = (__ \ "top").json.pick.map {
    case obj: JsObject =>
      new Datas(obj.keys.flatMap(k => (obj \ k).validate[Internal].asOpt
        .map(v => Data(k, v))).toSeq)

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but how I will have currentFieldName as there is multiple keys at same level and it is dynamic. I need all the values for that level.

Comment: Is it possible to read c and d as well and store into Data object?

Comment: @RahulJ It seems the 'b' within your data example may come with different type. This would mean you'll have to do polymorphic deserialization. i.e. Depends on the data type you may deserialize to StringArrayInternal or IntInternal. In your  caller use a match statement to discriminate between these.